# Given an object with multiple records, how to determine the count per field?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Given the rails object @messages, which contacts the following:

```
<Message id: 6, sender_id: 2, message: "123">
<Message id: 61, sender_id: 2, message: "stuff abc">
<Message id: 631, sender_id: 2, message: "hello world">
<Message id: 3, sender_id: 4, message: "hello world">
```

How can I determine the count per unique sender_id. Meaning outputting:

```
2 | 3
4 | 1
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `count`

```
@messages.count(:id, group: :sender_id)
```

which will output a hash

```
{ 2 => 3, 4 => 1 }
```

if you need to output it like in your question

```
@messages.count(:id, group: :sender_id).each do |sender_id, count|
  puts "#{sender_id} | #{count}"
end
```

Comment: That is really cool. thank you. I'll mark this as the answer when StackOverflow lets me